C# Selenium naming convention for IWebElement with parameter
Had this come up in a code review and cannot find any good answers on it on the internet. When creating an IWebElement that takes in a parameter, should the parameter be camelCase or PascalCase?
Example: private IWebElement GridRow(string rowIndex) => driver.findElement(By.XPath($"//somexpath{rowIndex}"));
Should it be rowIndex or RowIndex?
Team members have differing opinions, I know method parameters use camelCase but am just not sure about these parameters

"✔️ DO use PascalCasing for all public member, type, and namespace names consisting of multiple words.
✔️ DO use camelCasing for parameter names."  So if that is a parameter, then MS says to camelCase:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions
